# Tables with Pweave

Tags: python

[xtables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/) allows the generation of proper LaTeX tables with [Sweave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave). Is there an equivalent package for [Pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/docs.html)? What's the best way to add tables to dynamic LaTeX/Python reports?

```
%
% virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
% source ./venv/bin/activate
% pip install --upgrade pweave
% pip install --upgrade pandas
% pweave -f tex pweavetest.texw
% pdflatex pweavetest.tex
%

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the \texttt{tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of \texttt{age} with the innformation in \texttt{age\_colour}.

<<echo=False>>=
import pandas as pd

pupils = {'name':['Jeff','Lisa','Sam','Victoria'],'age':[26,34,6,68],'age_colour':['white','white','red','white']}

table = pd.DataFrame(pupils, columns = ['name', 'age'])

table
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a small example Python file that compiles with Pweave, where you would like to add a table? This would make it easier for people that are interested in answering to start working on an approach instead of needing to start from scratch. Furthermore it would ensure that and solutions provided actually match your setup, so the solutions given will be useful for you.

Comment: Knitr is an improved Sweave replacement that allow R chunks but also python chunks. This not solve make the table in phyton but if you can use both languages with the same tool in the same report you can pass python pandas to R dataframes in some way. I have not experience in python,  but I see that there are the library `feather` to do this. There is also `reticulate` that claim to be an interface to Python  (`reticulate`) but in any case, you can always export some data in a csv file in a python chunk,  and then read the csv file in R in the next chunk to use xtable.

Comment: @Marijn [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lars20070/ac64788e0316144013ff2abdb3c29735/raw/4d3eee103311a756b3b47b854b72fd840bd33c03/gistfile1.txt) a minimal example. I would like to have more control e.g. set the background colour of the table cells. Thanks.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for pointing out `knitr`. Maybe LaTeX + Python + knitr + [knitr::kable](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) is a good combination. I would like to avoid `R` entirely and do not want to use `reticulate`.

Comment: @lars20070 thanks for the example code, I have added it into the question. Next time you can do that yourself (press the `edit` link at the bottom of the post). The idea is to make a question here on the site as self-contained as possible to avoid problems with changing links, so future visitors can still benefit from the question.

Comment: By the way I also changed `\tt` to `\texttt` in your code, as `\tt` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn. I will experiment with `knitr::kable` and see if that package allows me to set the table cell background colour dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below combines `age` and `age_colour` into a single column which is then processed by the `formatter` function `f2`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the {\tt tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of {\tt age} with the information in {\tt age\_colour}.\\ \\

<<echo=False>>=
import pandas as pd

pupils = {'name':['Jeff','Lisa','Sam','Victoria'],'age':[26,34,6,68],'age_colour':['white','white','red','white']}

# combine 'age' and 'colour' in a single column (then pass to formatter function f2)
table = pd.DataFrame(pupils, columns = ['name', 'age', 'age_colour'])
table['age'] = table['age'].astype(str) + '_' + table['age_colour'].astype(str)
table = table[['name', 'age']]
@

<<echo=False, results='tex'>>=
def f1(x):
  return str(x)

def f2(x):
  # split argument into 'age' and 'age_colour'
  split = x.split('_')
  age = split[0]
  colour = split[1]
  return '\cellcolor{'+str(colour)+'}{'+str(age)+'}'

print(table.to_latex(index=False, column_format='|l|c|', formatters=[f1,f2], escape=False))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` Python library has a `to_latex()` function to convert dataframes into LaTeX tables. You can use that in Pweave by setting a block to `results='tex'`. The exact string `'tex'` is arbitrary, anything other than `verbatim` or `hidden` means raw text, which is the intended format here (see [http://mpastell.com/pweave/chunks.html#envvar-results='verbatim'](http://mpastell.com/pweave/chunks.html#envvar-results=%27verbatim%27)).

The `to_latex()` method requires the `booktabs` LaTeX package so you need to add a `\usepackage` statement for that to your `.texw` template.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % this package added
\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the \texttt{tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of \texttt{age} with the information in \texttt{age\_colour}.

<<echo=False>>=
import pandas as pd

pupils = {'name':['Jeff','Lisa','Sam','Victoria'],'age':[26,34,6,68],'age_colour':['white','white','red','white']}

table = pd.DataFrame(pupils, columns = ['name', 'age'])
@
<<echo=False, results='tex'>>=
print(table.to_latex())
@

\end{document}
```

Result (.tex):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the \texttt{tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of \texttt{age} with the information in \texttt{age\_colour}.

\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
{} &      name &  age \\
\midrule
0 &      Jeff &   26 \\
1 &      Lisa &   34 \\
2 &       Sam &    6 \\
3 &  Victoria &   68 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result (pdf):

[image]

Comment: I see now that the question was also about table cell color, this will be rather more difficult (presumably requiring a new implementation of a Python function for converting a dataframe into a table), but maybe it can be done somehow with built-in options to `to_latex()`, I'll check later about that.

Comment: Thank you! [to_latex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) gives me a lot of control. Very cool. Maybe `formatters` will allow me to set `\cellcolor{}` in the table dynamically.

Comment: @lars20070 if you find a solution using those formatters then it would be good to add that as an answer here (the site allows to answer your own question). If you find something that looks interesting but you can't really get it to work properly then you can either add some information to the current question (using the `edit` button) or ask a new question if you think it is very different from the current question (and then provide a link to this question to give context for the new question).

Comment: The formatters option in to_latex works alright. But any \ are interpreted as \textbackslash. Hence, I cannot pass LaTeX commands via the formatter function. Not sure how to pass the cell color.

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas command `to_latex` does not allow to return LaTeX instructions. Guess it would be best to extend [`to_latex`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/io/formats/test_to_latex.py) with a new `cellcolor` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the {\tt tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of {\tt age} with the innformation in {\tt age\_colour}.\\ \\

<<echo=False>>=
import pandas as pd

pupils = {'name':['Jeff','Lisa','Sam','Victoria'],'age':[26,34,6,68],'age_colour':['white','white','red','white']}

table = pd.DataFrame(pupils, columns = ['name', 'age'])
@

<<echo=False, results='tex'>>=
def f1(x):
  return str(x)

def f2(x):
  % TODO: Not possible to return LaTeX instructions. Backslashes returned as \textbackslash.
  return '\cellcolor{\'red\'}{'+str(x)+'}'

print(table.to_latex(index=False, column_format='|l|c|', formatters=[f1,f2]))
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can switch off the conversion from `\ ` to `\textbackslash` with `print(table.to_latex(index=False, column_format='|l|c|', formatters=[f1,f2], escape=False))`. Note that other special characters will also be affected by this, which might result in errors (for example if you have a column called `Amount ($)` or something, which contains a `$` character, that needs to be escaped).

Comment: Also the color names should not be in quotes, just `red` instead of `'red'`.

Answer (score 0):

[to_latex](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/io/formats/test_to_latex.py) in Pandas and [table](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/longtable.html) in PyLaTeX are good ways to implement dynamic LaTeX tables. Thanks to @Marijn and @alan-xiang for pointing me in these directions. [Dynamic cell background colours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572323/dynamic-table-cell-background-colours-with-latex-python-pweave) are discussed in a separate question.