# dynamic table cell background colours with LateX/Python/Pweave

Tags: python

I am using LaTeX, Python and Pweave for the generation of dynamic reports. Panda `to_latex` and its option `formatters` allow me to include tables. But how could I set the table cell background color i.e. set `cellcolor` dynamically?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the {\tt tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of {\tt age} with the innformation in {\tt age\_colour}.\\ \\

<<echo=False>>=
import pandas as pd

pupils = {'name':['Jeff','Lisa','Sam','Victoria'],'age':[26,34,6,68],'age_colour':['white','white','red','white']}

table = pd.DataFrame(pupils, columns = ['name', 'age'])
@

<<echo=False, results='tex'>>=
def f1(x):
  return str(x)

def f2(x):
  return '\cellcolor{\'red\'}{'+str(x)+'}'

print(table.to_latex(index=False, column_format='|l|c|', formatters=[f1,f2]))
@
```

Comment: Maybe you can use PyLaTeX https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/

Comment: @AlanXiang [Tables in PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/pylatex/pylatex.table.html?highlight=table#module-pylatex.table) are not supporting cell background colours. Guess it is a new feature request that needs to be implemented.

Comment: @Iars20070 But why can't you add `\cellcolor` command in the cell yourself? It's not terribly hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by combining the value (`age`) and colour (`age_colour`) in a single column. Maybe there is another, more elegant solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\section*{Tables with LaTeX and Pweave}

The table below list the names and ages of pupils. How can I dynamically generate LaTeX tables i.e. using the {\tt tabular}  LaTeX environment? I would like to set the table cell colour of {\tt age} with the information in {\tt age\_colour}.\\ \\

<<echo=False>>=
import pandas as pd

pupils = {'name':['Jeff','Lisa','Sam','Victoria'],'age':[26,34,6,68],'age_colour':['white','white','red','white']}

# combine 'age' and 'colour' in a single column (then pass to formatter function f2)
table = pd.DataFrame(pupils, columns = ['name', 'age', 'age_colour'])
table['age'] = table['age'].astype(str) + '_' + table['age_colour'].astype(str)
table = table[['name', 'age']]
@

<<echo=False, results='tex'>>=
def f1(x):
  return str(x)

def f2(x):
  # split argument into 'age' and 'age_colour'
  split = x.split('_')
  age = split[0]
  colour = split[1]
  return '\cellcolor{'+str(colour)+'}{'+str(age)+'}'

print(table.to_latex(index=False, column_format='|l|c|', formatters=[f1,f2], escape=False))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]